# How create an empty array of "View" on SwiftUI?

Tags: arrays, xcode, view, swiftui

I wanted to have an empty array of "View" in SwiftUI and fill it later.

When I write it like this:

```
 @State var pages: [View]
```

XCode yells at me with this:

```
Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly not recommend to do that, but if you do like then there are two possible options

1. either declare as of view type erasure

```
@State var pages = [AnyView]()
```

2. or your specific concrete page type, let's assume it is `PageView`

```
@State var pages = [PageView]()
```

Comment: for option1 I get this error when I want to fill the pages variable: Cannot convert value of type 'YourView.page1.Type' to expected element type 'Array<AnyView>.ArrayLiteralElement' (aka 'AnyView')

Comment: Option2 is not possible too, I want to use the exact View thing, a complete page for that

Comment: What is AnyView for... https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-return-different-view-types

Comment: Aha ! I should cast my final view to AnyView!